# Adding images to raster field in batch

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, file-geodatabase, table, batch

I have about 300 records in an attribute table that each need an image to go with them. I've created a raster field on the table, and I've got all the needed images as rasters in the same GDB. I've been going through each record and manually adding the appropriate raster in editor.

Is there a script out there for doing this all at once?

Comment: Are you creating a mosaic dataset or a custom table that happens to contain a raster?

Comment: Its a custom table that contains a raster field

Comment: I can't see anything for python, the help indicates that it needs to be done manually... the only code is .net http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000038t000000. Rasters, blobs etc.. are special and can't be calculated or copied like other fields. Visual Studio .net express 2010 is a free download that works with ArcGis provided you stick to the license terms.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help. How are you at VB / C#?

Comment: Pretty much illiterate, I understand the basics of Python

Comment: As an estimate you might be better off doing this manually using the instructions http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t000001np000000 than trying to learn .net from scratch - provided this is a one-off event, if you want to do this frequently it would be worth learning: download .net express 2010 (not 2013), install the SDK and follow some of the basic examples - more help available at this site. You can access .net from python but that's quite advanced.

Comment: Ok good to know. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

[Attachments](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m900000002000000) may be useful here. If so then you can use the [Generate Attachment Match Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000157000000) to batch load your images.